# SheetAPI - NamedRanges

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

How to understand if namedRange contains a merged cell?
I need to use separate merged cell and basic range which contains few cells
All what I have about range
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvHs4.png).

````
range = {Range@18739}.         
 sheetId = {Integer@14464} 0.    
 startRowIndex = {Integer@14464} 0.    
 startColumnIndex = {Integer@14693} 4.   
 endRowIndex = {Integer@14748} 6.   
 endColumnIndex = {Integer@14783} 7.   
 rangeCoordinates = "E1:G6".   
 unboundedRange = false.   
 cells = {Integer@14785} 18.       ```
````